# Powershell SecureString Encrypt/Decrypt To Plain Text Not Working

Tags: powershell, encryption

We are trying to store a user password in the registry as a secure string but we can not seem to find a way to convert it back to plain text. Is this possible with SecureString?

Here is the simple test script we are trying to use...

```
Write-Host "Test Start..."
$PlainPassword = "@SomethingStupid" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force

$BSTR = ` [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($PlainPassword)
$PlainPassword = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto($BSTR)
Write-Host "Password is: " $PlainPassword
Read-Host
```

This is the error we are getting...

```
The term ' [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR'
is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At C:\test.ps1:4 char:71
+ $BSTR = ` [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR
<<<< ($PlainPassword)
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (
[System.Runtim...ureStringToBSTR:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Cannot find an overload for "PtrToStringAuto" and the argument count: "1".
At C:\test.ps1:5 char:75
+ $PlainPassword =
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto <<<< ($BSTR)
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodCountCouldNotFindBest
```

Comment: Try without wrapping the $BTSR line with the back tick

Comment: Give me a syntax error... "Unexpected Token"

Comment: Ok, try actually putting the plaintext in its own string variable first like in the article I think you were looking at - http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4546.working-with-passwords-secure-strings-and-credentials-in-windows-powershell.aspx

Comment: Hmm - what OS, .NET and Powershell versions are you running?

Comment: Sorry you're right, the back tick was the issue. When I originally removed it I took the first character off the command and that was the unexpected token error.

Comment: Glad you got there - I was doing this on a phone so couldn't go run the code but I've used these methods in my own scripts so I knew they looked OK, it was the back tick that stuck out immediately. I've used it many times to make code look/read better but it has bit me in the backside in this way more than once!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

What is with the backtick in the `$BSTR = ...` line?  I agree with Graham above. If I remove the backtick it work just fine:

```
$PlainPassword = "@SomethingStupid" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$BSTR = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($PlainPassword)
$PlainPassword = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto($BSTR)
Write-Host "Password is: " $PlainPassword
```

Outputs:

```
Password is:  @SomethingStupid
```

You're not trying to run this on something like Windows RT or some other PowerShell configuration where the language is restricted - are you?

Answer (score 16):

Here's a kludgy but much simpler way to decrypt a secure string, taking advantage of the fact that the [PSCredential class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Management.Automation.PSCredential%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) has a constructor that accepts the password as a secure string and a method (**GetNetworkCredential**) that returns that password in plain text:

```powershell
(New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential 'N/A', $secure_string).GetNetworkCredential().Password
```

Although it's intended for use with credentials, there's nothing that prevents you from using this to decrypt any secure string* regardless of purpose, supplying a dummy argument for the username (the username argument can't be null or an empty string, but any meaningless string will do).

---

<sub>* Under the context of the account that encrypted the secure string to begin with, of course</sub>

Comment: Perfect. It allowed me to retrieve a previously ConvertTo-SecureString password stored in a file to then pass it to the Invoke-SqlCmd.

Comment: What's "kludgy" about this?  I can store a PS securestring in a database field, retrieve it, put it in a PSCredential object and use this method to decrypt it.  Awesome!

Comment: It's not just account specific, but also machine unless you've used the `-Key` or `-SecureKey` options in `ConvertFrom-SecureString` to move it over.  
I love this because it's a one-liner.